# python library for bitwise storage?

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I need the need to be able to encode/decode some application 'constants' into a single variable.

the best description would be analogous to the octal notation in chmod , and would work something like this :

```
class Permissions(MagicalExistingClassSomewhere):
     EXECUTE = 1
     WRITE = 2
     READ = 4

a = Permissions(6)
print a
> [ Permissions.READ , Permissions.WRITE ]
a.add( Permissions.EXECUTE )
print a
> [ Permissions.READ , Permissions.WRITE , permissions.EXECUTE ]
print a.encode()
> 7
a.remove( Permissions.READ )
print a.encode()
> 3
```

has anyone seen a library that can abstract all the bitwise operations like this ?  I've looked throughout PyPi and seen some libraries that focus on `enum` and `bitwise`, but nothing really does this sort of stuff.

Comment: Typically, people make do with an integer and bitwise operations. While I agree that an API as in your example is more aesthetic and possibly more safe, I don't think it's worth the dependency for most people. Are you hell bent on abstracting the bitwise operations away?

Comment: yeah, the bitwise operations need to be hidden -- they can be confusing for entry-level and junior devs.  i've had too many people make mistakes with this stuff before.   i coded up something fast that can handle most of my needs.

Comment: whats confusing about `Permission.READ|Permission.WRITE` ?

Comment: ... If bitwise operations are confusing to entry-level and junior devs then THEY SHOULDN'T BE DEVELOPERS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some discussion and some source code for this kind of thing at  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/23187/bitwise-flag-code-for-python

It allows you to set flags like:

```
# define your flags
class sec(FlagType):
  admin = 1
  read = 2
  write = 4
  usage = 8

flags = +sec.read -sec.write +sec.usage

flags.read
>>> True
```

Lots of feedback saying its not Pythonic though :)